# How to get the resource loading time of a specific resource through CDP protocol or the console of DevTools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

How to get the resource loading time of a specific resource through CDP protocol or the console of DevTools?

[image]

I can obtain the load time of resources in the following way, but this should only correspond to the load from cache time in the above picture

```js
performance.getEntries().find((item)=>item.initiatorType==='link' && item.name.indexOf('') > -1)?.duration
```